# how to set opacity/transparent in DirectionPathOverlay class <class to draw path>

Tags: java, android, google-maps, paint, driving-directions

if we make an application to make route/path using android and google maps, we can use class **DirectionPathOverlay** to make line from one point to other, but i cant make the line more transparent **(not 100% transparent)**, it makes street name cant read clearly, can anyone help me?

here some code from DirectionPathOverlay class

```
 public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow, long when) {
        Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();
        if (shadow == false) {
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint.setStrokeJoin(Join.ROUND);
            Point point = new Point();
            projection.toPixels(gp1, point);
            paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);

            Point point2 = new Point();
            projection.toPixels(gp2, point2);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(4);
            canvas.drawLine((float) point.x, (float) point.y, (float) point2.x,
                    (float) point2.y, paint);
        }
        return super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow, when);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `paint.setAlpha(200);` this function accepts an Integer from 0 to 255.

Comment: Why does'nt this work for me? I cant change the alpha value with anything

Comment: Why u can't change it? it gives u error or u change it but the opacity remain the same?